# Can I tee from a refrigerator water supply for a coffee maker spigot?

Tags: plumbing, water

I'm going to be putting in a reverse osmosis water filtration system and running a water line to the refrigerator for the water/ice supply.

On the counter next to the refrigerator is where we keep our coffee maker.
We've found that filling up the reservoir from the fridge water supply is kind of annoying.

I had an idea of teeing off the fridge supply and putting a spigot under the cabinet over the coffee maker, so we could more easily fill it.

I believe that the filter uses either PEX or PERT tubing, so running it where I want it to go shouldn't be a big hassle, but I'm not sure what the best way of having a spigot would be.

I'm not above jury-rigging something if the whole idea isn't faulty.

Comment: If it were me, I’d get a new coffee maker that is designed to be direct-plumbed and bring the pipe over for that. Otherwise, you should look at “pot fillers” which are water faucets designed for installation over stoves. You could also look at wall-mount faucets that you might see in a bathroom.

Comment: Other thing to search for are 'water dispenser spigot' (which gets a lot of small things that could be horizontally mounted) and 'flexible pot filler' which gets pot fillers that are a bit of flex hose instead of being articulated out from the wall or counter. There's probably something on one of those that you could make work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decided I should up update the question with the solution I came up with.
[image]

I put a T into the line that went into the fridge, and then brought it around under the cabinet with a push button water valve that is kept in place with a 3d printed bracket, and the hose is held up under the cabinet by a magnet inside a 3d printed collar.

To fill the coffee maker I pull the tube down and put it into the coffee maker reservoir and hold the button. Since the water can't be left on I'm not too worried about not having a catch basin and drain.

It's also great for filling water bottles and the like.

It works pretty good, and spills are small and rare.

In the off chance that I have a problem with the valve I also put a water shutoff on the line. It has come in handy on the few times I had to lubricate the valve seals.

Answer (score 1):

The same places that sell RO filters sell spigots. Drill a hole in the countertop and drop it in, tighten the clamping nut below, attach the waterline.

If you want it to sprout from the cabinet above, you'll be more in a jury-rigging place. If you don't mind crude, a simple valve poking out on a tube is easy, but anything like a finished tap/faucet for that application is likely to be hard to find.

The lack of a drain under it could present some possible problems if it drips or if you flip it on to fill the coffeemaker and forget it. That's why they are usually associated with sinks.

Comment: Hmm, gives me a few things to think about. The counter is granite, so I'm not sure I want to try drilling it, even if the wife will let me, and the sink part is a good point.